# Using 'if' within a 'while' loop in Bash

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I have these diff results saved to a file:

```
bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/voo
18633a18634
> sashabrokerSTP
18634a18636
> sashatraderSTP
21545a21548
> yheemustr
```

I just really need the logins:

```
bash-3.00$ cat /tmp/voo | egrep ">|<"
> sashaSTP
> sasha
> yhee
bash-3.00$
```

But when I try to iterate through them and just print the names I get errors.
I just do not understand the fundamentals of using "if" with "while loops".
Ultimately, I want to use the `while` loop because I want to do something to the lines - and apparently `while` only loads one line into memory at a time, as opposed to the whole file at once.

```
bash-3.00$ while read line; do  if [[ $line =~ "<" ]] ; then  echo $line ; fi ;  done <  /tmp/voo
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$ while read line; do  if [[ egrep "<" $line ]] ; then  echo $line ; fi ;  done    <  /tmp/voo
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `"<"'
bash-3.00$
bash-3.00$ while read line; do  if [[ egrep ">|<" $line ]] ; then  echo $line ; fi ;  done <  /tmp/voo
bash: conditional binary operator expected
bash: syntax error near `|<"'
bash-3.00$
```

There has to be a way to loop through the file and then do something to each line. Like this:

```
bash-3.00$ while read line; do  if [[ $line =~ ">" ]];
 then echo $line |  tr ">" "+" ;
 if [[ $line =~ "<" ]];
 then echo $line | tr "<" "-" ;
 fi ;
 fi ;
 done  < /tmp/voo


+ sashab
+ sashat
+ yhee
bash-3.00$
```

Comment: Don't quote your regex in Bash 4.x.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be checking for `>`, not `<`, no?

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ">" ]]; then
        echo $line
    fi
done < /tmp/voo
```

Comment: sometimes on the diff the angle brackets go either way.  Usually signifying  > and add and < as a delte. Ultimately I want to sed-subistitue the '<' for "has been added: $line " and '>' "has been deleted: $line"

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need regex here? The following shell glob can also work:

```
while read line; do [[ "$line" == ">"* ]] && echo "$line"; done < /tmp/voo
```

**OR use AWK**:

```
awk '/^>/ { print "processing: " $0 }' /tmp/voo
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` will do:

```
$ grep -oP '> \K\w+' <<END
18633a18634
> sashabrokerSTP
18634a18636
> sashatraderSTP
21545a21548
> yheemustr
END
```

```
sashabrokerSTP
sashatraderSTP
yheemustr
```