# Awk conditional inside bash while loop

Tags: bash, if-statement, awk, while-loop, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a while loop that goes through a text file line by line, tests whether a field is blank using Awk, then does an action based on whether that condition is true or false.

The input file is this:

```
$ cat testarr.csv
cilantro,lamb,oranges
basil,,pears
sage,chicken,apples
oregano,,bananas
tumeric,turkey,plums
pepper,,guavas
allspice,goose,mangos
```

My expected output is:

```
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
```

based on [Using 'if' within a 'while' loop in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360151/using-if-within-a-while-loop-in-bash) and similar threads, I did this:

```
#!/bin/bash

error=ItIsBlank
success=ItIsNotBlank
while read LINE; do
echo this_is_one_iteration
QZ1=$(awk -F "," '{print (!$2)}')
if [[ $QZ1==0 ]] ; then
    echo $error
else
    echo $success
fi
done < testarr.csv
```

which gave me:

```
$ bash testloop.sh
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
```

So it doesn't even seem to be iterating through the file. However, if I take out the conditional, it iterates just fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

error=ItIsBlank
success=ItIsNotBlank
while read LINE; do
echo this_is_one_iteration
done < testarr.csv
```

gives:

```
$ bash testloop.sh
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
this_is_one_iteration
```

also, the conditional seems to work OK when not using awk:

```
QZ1=test
while read LINE; do
echo this_is_one_iteration
if [[ $QZ1=="test" ]] ; then
    echo It_worked
fi
done < testarr.csv
```

Gives me:

```
$ bash testloop.sh
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
this_is_one_iteration
It_worked
```

Comment: So you want to do this in `bash` script or an `Awk` command?

Comment: I don't care. I just need to test whether a field is blank and then do bash stuff based on that. Why doesn't it work to pass the output of awk to bash?

Comment: the _proper_ line is with 3 fields and the improper ones have less than 3?

Comment: Not necessarily, although in this specific example that happens to be true. So no, simply testing the number of fields in the line will not help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is correct except for a minor error. Add echo $LINE and pipe it to the awk statement. Awk in your script has no input to work on.

```
#!/bin/bash 

error=ItIsBlank
success=ItIsNotBlank
while read LINE; do
echo this_is_one_iteration
QZ1=$(echo $LINE|awk -F "," '{print (!$2)}')
if [[ $QZ1 -eq 0 ]] ; then
 echo $error
else
 echo $success 
fi
done < testarr.csv
```

When i run the script now:

```
[ec2-user@ip check]$ ./script.sh
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration 
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
```

Hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: Thanks, that almost worked, but the == operator didn't work in this context, instead I used -eq and that gave the expected output

Comment: Glad it worked . Please Close the thread if the issue is resolved . I have edited the answer in case someone else comes across the same problem

Comment: The problem wasn't `==` vs. `-eq`, it was that you need spaces around the operator. `==` (or `=`) test for string equality, `-eq` tests for numeric equality. In this case, either would work.

Answer (score 0):

> tests whether a field is blank using Awk

I suppose, it can be achieved  with single **awk** process:

```
awk -F, '{ print "this_is_one_iteration"; f="Not"; 
           for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="") { f="";break }; printf "ItIs%sBlank\n",f }' testarr.csv
```

The output:

```
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsBlank
this_is_one_iteration
ItIsNotBlank
```

Comment: But will this allow the result of the truth test to execute bash code? My point wasn't to print "ItIsBlank", I was just echoing that as a test of ability to send it to bash.